# ¿Se puede aplicar vista filtro por usuario a un spreadsheet desde script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Esta funcion es correcta, pero lo que hace es aplicarme el filtro a todos los usuarios que esta conectados. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de aplicarlo a un solo usuario, osea tipo vista filtro, sin que se le aplicase tambien a los otros usuarios conectados.

```
  function onOpen(){
  
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    
    var filterSettings = {};
    var currentUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Hoja1');
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
    sheet.showRows(1, numRows);
  

    // The range of data on which you want to apply the filter.
    // optional arguments: startRowIndex, startColumnIndex, endRowIndex, endColumnIndex
    if (currentUser == 'usuario@gmail.com'){
      Logger.log(currentUser);
  
      filterSettings.range = {
        sheetId: ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()
      };

      // Criteria for showing/hiding rows in a filter
      // https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/FilterCriteria
      filterSettings.criteria = {};
      var columnIndex = 3;
      filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex] = {
        'hiddenValues': ["Mi filtro"]
      };

      var request = {
        "setBasicFilter": {
          "filter": filterSettings
        }
      };
       Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

El filtro básico se aplica a todos los usuarios, en su lugar podrías usar una vista de filtro pero esta vista no se puede activar de forma automática ya que la única forma de modificar la interfaz de usuario es mediante el Spreadsheet Service de Google Apps Script y este no incluye un método para ello.

Una opción es que le muestres al usuario un diálogo con instrucciones sobre las vistas de filtro.

Recursos

- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters

Comment: Lo que yo necesitaba es que determinados usuarios solo accedieran a una parte de mi hoja, pero tienen que poder editar. Sería que accedieran directamente a una vista filtro y que no pudieran eliminarla. ¿Eso por lo que veo no es posible noÇ?